# How can I get the parent's parent's width in HTML with CSS?

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:960px;">
       <div style="width:30%;">
            <div>Hello World!</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the width of "Hello World!" div same as "wrapper" div with css?

Comment: And why you set `width`s if you don't want them?

Comment: you need to remove width 960px and 30% if you want hello world to be of wrapper width

Comment: This depends **a lot** on your context. What positioning, how wide is 100% really etc.

Comment: I'm working on a project that it's written. I need to change the style but when I use javascript it conflicts. Now I have this problem. I wanna know what if there is something with css to help me or not

Comment: Sounds like you have either a 1) maintenance problem or 2) Javascript problem instead.

Comment: Dear G.L.P yes I know that. But if I do that other things would have been destroy in style of my project

Comment: Dear Nit what do you mean by how wide is 100%? of course it depends which screen you see the page

Comment: post all the relevant code / share expected output as image.. so we can try to help you

Comment: @atousadarabi <- By the way, you call people like that.

Answer (score 4):

To give something a width relative to one of its ancestors, one solution is to give the ancestor `position:relative` and the element itself `position:absolute`.

```css
/* make the three divs visible, to demonstrate the effect */

div {background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.3)}

/* the main point to the solution */

#wrapper {position:relative}
#wrapper > div > div {position:absolute}

/* some cleaning up of the side effects */

#wrapper > div::after {content:'\200B'}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:960px;">
       <div style="width:30%;">
            <div>Hello World!</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see when you display the snippet at full page, the innermost div (with the darkest background color) is 30% of the width of the outermost one, even if there is a fixed width div in between.

Unless you meant something else, in which case I apologise, but then you should explain yourself better.